# Why system keep ask to enter password for the first member of sudo group instead of deny command execution

Tags: permissions, sudo, users, pam

We have OS ubuntu 18.04. There are 2 users presented :
user1, user2. user1 is administrative account and is member of sudo group:
`uid=1010(user1) gid=1010(user1) groups=1010(user1),27(sudo),110(lxd)`. user2 is a regular user `uid=1000(user2) gid=1000(user2) groups=1000(user2)`. 
Now, in /etc/sudoers file i have a default record for sudo group:

```
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command 
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

As well as special commands allowed to be executed with administrative(root) rights for user2:

```
Cmnd_Alias CMD_RELOAD_PHP_FPM = /bin/systemctl reload php7.0-fpm, /bin/systemctl reload php7.2-fpm
user2 ALL=(root:root) NOPASSWD: CMD_RELOAD_PHP_FPM
```

At this step all is fine user2 can execute everything specified in Cmnd_Alias without entering password, so work as expected.

But when user2 tries to execute something he is not allowed to he gets prompt to enter, attention, `user1` password. Not `root`, not his own `user2`, but `user1` password, instead of silently or informatively denying such action:

```
user2@someserver:~$ /bin/systemctl restart <someservice>
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to restart 'someservice.service'.
Authenticating as: user1
Password:
```

`user1` is the only member of sudo group.

```
grep 'sudo' /etc/group
sudo:x:27:user1
grep 'sudo' /etc/gshadow
sudo:*::user1
```

If `user1` is removed from `sudo` group and `user2` tries to execute same command, then he is asked to enter `root` password.

How can i change this behaviour, so `user2` attempts would be denied instead of asking him to enter password ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not enough knowledge about `polkit`, but it seems to be a cause of such behavior.

Line which responsible for that is :

```
AdminIdentities=unix-group:sudo;unix-group:admin
```

inside the `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/51-ubuntu-admin.conf` file

Commenting of the `AdminIdentities=...` line and restarting polkit daemon returns default behavior where `root` password is required for service restart.
Not sure if it's safe, or not. Probably some of community members could explain better.

Also it seems that I've found the place where default actions for `systemd` are described if unprivileged user is trying to perform some action with the systemd service.
It's inside the file: `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.systemd1.policy`

If I'm setting values like this:

```
<action id="org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units">
        <description gettext-domain="systemd">Manage system services or other units</description>
        <message gettext-domain="systemd">Authentication is required to manage system services or other units.</message>
        <defaults>
                <allow_any>no</allow_any>
                <allow_inactive>no</allow_inactive>
                <allow_active>no</allow_active>
        </defaults>
</action>
```

i start to get `Access denied` message on trying to restart service as unprivileged user.